# Declaring memory for a struct pointer array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct in c as follows:

```
typedef struct edgenode
{
   int value;
   struct edgenode * next;
};
```

I wish to create an array of pointer of edgenodes.
So, I can do edgenode * array[50].

But, how do I go about allocating memory dynamically for this?
Will it be,

```
edgenode ** array = malloc(sizeof(edgenode)*50)?
```

Comment: Your code is correct but I'm not sure what you mean by ' I can do edgenode * array[50]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
edgenodes * array = malloc(50 * sizeof *array);
```

You can initilize it by `NULL` as follows

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
  array[i] = NULL;
```

For allocating memory for each instance you need

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
  array[i] = malloc(sizeof *array[i]);
```

Comment: Can you please explain this? Why I can't simply do edgenodes * array[50]. Won't that be enough for allocating memory for 50 nodes? Why do I need to allocate it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

```
edgenode *array[50];

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof array / sizeof *array; i++)
{
     array[i] = malloc(sizeof **array);
     /* add code to check for malloc failure */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating first the list of pointers, so:

```
edgenode ** array = (edgenode **) malloc(sizeof(edgenode *) * 50);
```

And then, for each one:

```
array[i] = (edgenode *) malloc(sizeof(edgenode));
```

Comment: Each struct in my case will have a size of 4 bytes. Now, by the first step, won't it allocate, 50*4 bytes? Why is it that I need to do the second step individually?

Comment: Each of your structs will have a pointer AND an int. So sizeof(int) + sizeof(edgenode *). Just save yourself the trouble and use sizeof(edgenode). And you need to allocate each one cause (edgenode **) means "pointers to pointers", so you allocate both the list of pointers and the content of the pointers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
Given your example code:

typedef struct edgenode
{
   int value;
   struct edgenode * next;
};

I wish to create an array of pointer of edgenodes. So, I can do edgenode * array[50].

But, how do I go about allocating memory dynamically for this? Will it be,

edgenode ** array = malloc(sizeof(edgenode)*50)?

My suggested response:
Using a typedef is a very poor idea, 
including that you have not given a reference name for the typedef.

a much better coding would be:

struct edgenode
{
   int value;
   struct edgenode * next;
};

Then, your question is a bit unclear on your final target.
If you mean that you want a local array of pointers to 50 instances of the 
struct edgenode
where the 50 instances of the struct are in dynamic memory (the heap).
then the following will work nicely:

struct edgenode *array[50] = {NULL}; // declare array and init to null

for( int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
    array[i] = (struct edgenode*)malloc( sizeof(struct edgenode) );
    if( NULL == array[i] )
    { // then, malloc failed
        ... handle malloc failure
    }
    memset( array[i], 0x00, sizeof( struct edgenode ) );
}

However, the above yields 50 separate dynamic memory segments, 
so 50 different free() calls would need to be made
and where LOTS of overhead and unused memory will be wasted
a better idea is:

$define edgenodeNum (50)

struct edgenode *edgenodePtr = 
    (struct edgenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct edgenode)*edgenodeNum );
if( NULL == edgenodePtr )
{
    .... handle malloc failure
}

memset( edgenodePtr, 0x00, (sizeof( struct edgenode ) * edgenodeNum) )
for( int i=0; i<edgenodeNum; i++ )
{
    array[i] = &(edgenodePtr[i]);
}


where there is very little wasted overhead/dynamic memory 
and where only one free() will need to be performed
```